# How to prevent focus steal from window in same application?

Tags: c#, winapi

Using `SetWindowLong()` and `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` I've made a window non-activatable.

- If I put the cursor in Notepad and click the non-activatable window the cursor remains active in Notepad.
- If I put the cursor in another window inside my application and click the non-activatable window the cursor will be removed from the other window.

I made a mini project to reproduce the issue: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=78888532457762447347

Basically a WPF application with two windows:

**MainWindow**

```
// XAML code
<Window x:Class="CS_test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Background="LightGray" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Width="300" Height="200"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>

// C# code
namespace CS_test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            new NonActiveWindow().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**NonActiveWindow**

```
// XAML code
<Window x:Class="CS_test.NonActiveWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="NonActiveWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

// C# code
namespace CS_test
{
    public partial class NonActiveWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
        private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;

        public NonActiveWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowInteropHelper windowHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            SetWindowLong(windowHelper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(windowHelper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
        }
    }
}
```

I know it is possible to fix the issue by instantiating `NonActiveWindow` in a separate thread (with a separate Dispatcher), but I can't use this approach due to threading issues.

**Is there a way to prevent the focus loss without creating the non-activatable window in a separate thread?**

*Edit:*

Video to show the issue (in response to Justins answer):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RNmJc7ya48

And just in case anyone wonders why the window isn't updated while dragging: [Create a window using the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE flag ,but it can't be dragged until I release the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051552/create-a-window-using-the-ws-ex-noactivate-flag-but-it-cant-be-dragged-until-i).

Comment: Take a look at this question [How to prevent a new WPF form from stealing focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456529/how-to-prevent-a-new-wpf-form-from-stealing-focus)

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue. This is some special behaviour when the windows have the same UI thread.

Comment: [SetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx): *"Certain window data is cached, so changes you make using **SetWindowLongPtr** will not take effect until you call the [**SetWindowPos**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) function."*

Comment: I tried calling SetWindowPos() after SetWindowLong() - no change.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am facing this problem and haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Negative. Implemented a workaround where I store window handles and ignore handles from windows inside my own application.

Comment: @Woodgnome hello! could you share the workaround you've implemented, would be much appreciated. thank you!

Comment: @IneedHelp if it's still applicable, you literally just start a new thread and create the window inside the thread handler:  `new Thread(() =>{ new Window(); ... }).Start()`. To force a `Dispatcher` to be created, add `Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;` inside the handler.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ShowActivated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showactivated(v=vs.110).aspx) property is working fine for me:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var otherWindow = new NonActiveWindow()
    {
        ShowActivated = false
    };
    otherWindow.Show();
}
```

My `OtherWindow` is just an empty WPF window and doesn't have any of the P/Invoke calls that your example has.

Note that `MainWindow` is shown very slightly *after* `OtherWindow` is shown because this call is in the constructor. If you want to fix this then you should call `Show` outside of the constructor, for example in the [`Loaded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Captured a video that should show the issue very clearly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RNmJc7ya48

Comment: Okay, I think I better understand what you are asking for now - I'm not sure I know how to do that.

Comment: @Woodgnome The video is private now. Can I see the video? I may be facing the same problem.

Comment: @SemihArtan odd, it's back to being public now.

Comment: @Woodgnome Hey thank you for paying attention to my request! This issue solved on [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70438220/two-window-app-where-one-has-ws-ex-noactivate) SO question.

Comment: @SemihArtan that's cool, I'll have to check it when I get time, but seems like it's a workaround that should get the job done (and quite simple to boot) 